# Best practice for deep copying an array of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I have this line of code:

```
var newMatrix = this.state.matrix;
```

I would like to set 'newMatrix' to a copy, not a reference, of 'this.state.matrix'. 'this.state.matrix' is a 2D array populated with React components which will eventually be rendered into a grid on the screen.

What would be best practice to deep copy it into the new variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: In case it doesn't have circular references, you could use this: `var newMatrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.matrix));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard procedure in this cases is to just traverse your data structure and manually copying the values or copying the references of sub-objects as you see fit.

Example:

```
class Dog {
    constructor() {
        this.tag = {name: "foo", material: "bar"};
    }
}

function copyDog(dog) {
    let _dog = new Dog();
    _dog.tag.name = dog.tag.name;
    _dog.tag.material = dog.tag.material;
    return _dog;
}

myDog = new Dog();
yourDog = copyDog(myDog);
```

And thus:

```
> myDog == yourDog;
false
```

This is not the only way and much depends on your implementation and the depth at to which you wish to copy.